# Can CString::Format() receive const std::string?

Tags: c++, constants, cstring

Can [CString::Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) receive const std::string?

Example:

```
void some_func( const std::string a_string )
{
    CString b_string("World");

    CString c_string;
    c_string.Format("%s %s!", a_string, b_string);

    /* print c_string */
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  You need to use the return value from `a_string.c_str()` (which is a `const char*` that CString can understand).

Comment: Thanks a million @Zac! So I guess the const was not the problem but actually having std::string as a parameter to CString::Format(). How come then that it compiled?!

Comment: If you've been programming for more than a couple of days, @Jonathan, you will know that lots of things compile even though they don't work. The `CString::Format` function receives all its format parameters in a `...` argument, which will accept values of any type. However, when the value is of a user-defined class type (which includes `std::string`), the C++ Standard says the behavior of the resultant program is undefined. Formally, using `CString` without a cast is undefined, too, but the class uses special tricks to make sure it works on any compilers that MFC supports.

Comment: It's hard to believe they would go the length to support CString but neglect std::string. Guess only MS could do that...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `std::string` to a `CString:`

```
CString a_cstring( a_string.c_str() );
```

Then use a_cstring.

```
c_string.Format("%s %s!", a_cstring, b_string);
```